# Why is Lucene numeric range search not working?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

The string `i` passed to search is `(Experience:[1 TO 5])` where it searches all the  numbers like 15, 25, 21, 51, etc. I need to search between the number 1 and 5,

```
using Lucene.Net.Store;

var results = new List<SearchResults>();

// Specify the location where the index files are stored
string indexFileLocation = @"G:\Lucene.Net\Data\Document";
var dir = Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.GetDirectory(indexFileLocation);
var reader = IndexReader.Open(dir);
var searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
var queryParser = new QueryParser("Prof_ID", analyzer);

// <default field> is the field that QueryParser will search if you don't 

string special = "";
if (!txtkeyword.Text.Equals(""))
{
    special = special + "(Experience:[1 TO 5])";
}

var hits = searcher.Search(queryParser.Parse(special));

// Getting result to the list
for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length(); i++)
{
    SearchResults result = new SearchResults();

    result.Skillsummarry = hits.Doc(i).GetField("JS_Skill_Summary").StringValue();
    result.Experience = hits.Doc(i).GetField("Experience").StringValue();
    result.Profile_Id = hits.Doc(i).GetField("Prof_ID").StringValue();

    results.Add(result);
}

GridView1.DataSource = results;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Sorry your question is not quite clear. Please edit your question and try to make clear what works and what you want to achieve.

Comment: You need to show how you are indexing the data, and what the data looks like.  This code just shows how you are querying the existing index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do a range-type query you should do,

```
var query = new TermRangeQuery(
    "Experience", 
    "1", 
    "5", 
    includeLower: true, 
    includeUpper: true);
```

However, that's if you stored your numbers as `string` which might return wrong ranges as it does a string comparison, not a numeric comparison; thus `"5" > "15"` is `true`, instead of the other way around.

To do a numeric range-type query you do,

```
var query = 
    NumericRangeQuery.NewDoubleRange(
        "Experience", 
        1, 
        5, 
        includeLower: true, 
        includeUpper: true);
```

However, you need to make sure when you index your documents, you store the `Experience` field as a numeric field rather than a standard one,

```
var field = 
    new NumericField("Experience", Field.Store.YES, true)
        .SetDoubleValue(15, 25, 21, 51, etc. );
```

before adding it to your Lucene document.

Comment: Thank you @rae1n.You guided me a right way to achieve my needs.